In rotation context, why is there a $r$ squared in the Moment of Inertia?
The moment of inertia, as defined, is a measure of the resistance to changes in angular acceleration.
From my understanding, the key parameters to consider are:

The distance from the axis of rotation (arm length, $r$) [This will capture the weight distribution involved]
The angle at which the force is applied at the point of contact
The mass

The value of $r$ determines the difficulty in achieving angular displacement.
Thus, the moment of inertia ($I$) can be quantified as:
$$I=mr$$
If we plot a graph between $r$ and angular displacement, we will observe a downward curve:

The $x$-axis represents the arm length ($r$), increasing to the right.
The $y$-axis represents the angular displacement.

Why is there an $r^2$ term in the textbook equation?
Please do not use Kinetic energy translation to show the $r^2$ since it is circular.
I would really appreciate if you can build the moment of inertia equation, please point out my holes so I can see this problem better.
Based on the comments:
To start, let's consider a rod of mass $ m $ and length $ l $, hinged at the center, with a force applied perpendicular to the end of the rod. In this scenario, the torque is given by:
$$
\tau = F \cdot l \cdot \sin(\theta)
$$
where $ \theta $ is $ 90^\circ $ because the force is applied perpendicular to the point of contact.
Now, a certain torque will result in a certain angular displacement. By varying $ l $, the angular displacement will change.
Angular acceleration is the rate of change of angular velocity, which itself is the rate of change of angular displacement:
$$
\omega = \frac{d \theta}{dt}
$$
Thus, angular acceleration is:
$$
\alpha = \frac{d \omega}{dt}
$$
I am aware that angular displacement is defined as
$$
\theta = \frac{ArcLength}{radius}
$$
so the radians covered is our angular displacement correct?
Linear:
$$ F = ma $$
Rotation context shouldn't this be the following as torque already captures the weight distribution ?
$$ \tau = m.\alpha $$
The quantities of angular velocity and angular acceleration are derived from angular displacement which is caused due to torque.
Please shed some light

Looks like you tried to use \(this\) LaTeX notation - on SE you need to use $dollar signs$/$$double dollar signs$$.

The definition of moment of inertia, as given in the post, differs from the commonly accepted definition, https://www.britannica.com/science/moment-of-inertia

The moment of inertia ($I$) can be quantified as $I=mr$. There are many ways to “quantify” a concept, but only some of them are actually useful. Your question is similar to asking why kinetic energy isn’t quantified as $m|\mathbf v|$.

With your suggestion the torque unit will be $~[kg,m/s]~ $ this doesn’t make sense

The moment of inertia depends on the shape of the potentialy rotating object and the axis of rotation.Generaly it is the integral of the moment of inertial of all infinitesmall masses which make up the object.So for some shapes it is ~R^2 but that is not a mandatory condition.

Please don't mar your post with edits indicating an answer was found; the green check mark you've given provides that information for all users.

Answer
Ladies and Gents:
To understand why the moment of inertia has ( r^2 ), I believe that we need to consider two contexts involved in rotation:

The tangential application
The angular effect

The force applied is tangential, and in this context, the linear equations are honored.
$$
\theta = \frac{\text{Arc Length}}{\text{radius}}
$$
The arc length is the linear equivalent of the displacement.
$$
\text{Arc Length} (s) = \theta \cdot \text{radius}
$$
Now, when we apply a force at a distance from the axis, quantified by torque, we observe angular acceleration.
Rearranging the expression for arc length from the above equation, it can be projected to the linear context. The rate at which tangential displacement takes place is tangential velocity.
$$
v_t = \frac{ds}{dt}
$$
Substituting:
$$
s = r \cdot \theta
$$
$$
v_t = r \cdot \frac{d(\theta)}{dt}
$$
$$
v_t = r \cdot \omega
$$
The rate of change of tangential velocity is tangential acceleration:
$$
a_t = \frac{d(v_t)}{dt}
$$
Substituting:
$$
a_t = r \cdot \alpha
$$
Now, bringing in torque:
$$
F_t = F \cdot \sin(\theta)
$$
$$
\tau = F_t \cdot r
$$
And the rotational analog of Newton's second law:
$$
\tau = I \cdot \alpha
$$
Equating the two:
$$
I \cdot \alpha = m \cdot a_t \cdot r
$$
Solving for ( I ):
$$
I \cdot \frac{a_t}{r} = m \cdot a_t \cdot r \cdot
$$
Hence, the moment of inertia ( I ) is:
$$
I = m \cdot r^2 \cdot
$$
Therefore, the moment of inertia is a representation of mass multiplied by ( r^2 ), where ( r ) is the distance from the axis of rotation.

That's not correct. Even the formula, you have derived for moment of inertia is wrong. I think you need to know about vectors and rotation context more deeply

Can you please elaborate and please do not edit my answer.

You used the wrong formula. $$\vec \tau = \vec r × \vec F$$

If we use the scaler form, it will be $$\tau = Fr sin\theta = F_t r$$

Thank you, I Updated the F and Ft representation.

Suppose we have a point mass $m$ and we apply a force $F$ to it then we get an acceleration $a$ given by Newton's second law:
$$ F = ma $$

To convert this to an angular calculation we simply pick a point $P$ at a distance $r$ from the mass, and for simplicity we make choose the point so $r$ is normal to the line of the force. The we define the torque and angular acceleration as:
$$\begin{align}
\tau &= rF \\
\alpha &= a/r
\end{align} $$
And we define the moment of inertia by using the angular version of Newton's second law:
$$ \tau = I\alpha $$
Rearranging gives:
$$ I = \tau/\alpha = r^2 F/a = r^2m $$
The $r^2$ term in the MOI is a consequence of our definitions of torque and angular acceleration.

Thank you, i update my question with a new section Based on the comments, with my understanding on this matter. Please help me if you can

Another way of looking at this is that angular momentum is $${\vec J} = {\vec r} \times {\vec p} \,.$$
For circular motion ${\vec p} = m {\vec v} = m {\vec \omega} \times {\vec r}$. Using $${\vec a} \times {\vec b} \times {\vec c} = ({\vec a} \cdot {\vec c}) {\vec b} - ({\vec a} \cdot {\vec b}) {\vec c}$$ you find $${\vec J} = mr^2 {\vec \omega} \,,$$ hence $$I=mr^2 \,. $$

You want an insight of Moment of Inertia without the concept of work - energy? That won't workout. Let me explain why.
How did those terms come?
After Newton brought a new era in Physics with his three laws of motion, Classical mechanics was in its full swing and physicists then were solely concentrated upon describing the motion of objects. While describing the kinematics of rotation or circular motion, they realised that it was hard to explain the kinematics only with linear terms (just think how the velocity vector is constantly changing in any curvilinear motion). So, some new terms were introduced as a solution. Those are angular displacement, angular velocity and angular acceleration i.e the angular counterparts of displacement, velocity and acceleration.
The same problem was faced when dealing with the rotational dynamics. To find out a solution, they started looking for the angular counterparts of force, inertia (i.e mass in linear motion) and momentum with which they can relate angular terms in kinematics. These were found to be torque, moment of inertia and angular momentum respectively. This was done by using work - energy equations that relate kinematics and dynamics terms, and the principle of Conservation of Mechanical Energy.
N.B: These terms are purely mathematical and are used to match results.

Moment of Inertia
Galileo was the first person in modern times who came up the concept of Inertia. Although he thoroughly experimented inertia for both linear and angular motion, he never found any unified theory to generalize the motion of objects. It all happened after the exceptional work in mechanics by Sir Issac Newton as mentioned earlier.
Now, we shall try to understand the concept of moment of Inertia. Let's assume you have ping pong ball tied with a thread and you are rotating the ball horizontally. Now you try to rotate it with changing the length of the thread. Choose two lengths of the thread to be $R$ and $r$ where $R>r$. Now if in the both cases same energy is given to the ball, the latter will have greater angular velocity than former. If this is violated, then the former may have same angular velocity or greater. Thus the ball will also have equal or more speed (acc. to $v=R\omega$) and will cover more distance in the same time as compared to latter. But why should it happen? After all same energy was provided in both cases. So both must have same same speed and different angular velocities (here $\omega_R<\omega_r$). From this contradiction it is clear that how fast an object will rotate due to some force doesn't only depend upon its mass (which dependency is obvious) but also on the distance from rotation axis. As inertia is the property to resist motion, analogically there must exist some kind of inertia that resists angular motion different from mass or linear inertia. That's Moment of Inertia.
Derivation
The popular derivation of moment of inertia goes this way (I suppose you already know this). Assume a point mass $m$ is rotating around a point O at a distance $r$ with linear velocity $v$ and angular velocity $\omega$. Hence,
$$v=r\omega$$
$$E_k=\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{1}{2}mr^2{\omega}^2$$
Now saying analogically, to get more linear velocity providing same energy we need to reduce the mass or linear inertia $m$ whether incase of circular motion we have to reduce the term $mr^2$ to get more angular velocity. This suggests that $mr^2$ is equivalent to inertia in angular motion (just like mass is equivalent to inertia in linear motion).
So, the Moment of Inertia $I$ can be described by the equation
$$I=mr^2$$
Note that, the word 'Moment' suggests illusion. The Moment of Inertia is more or less the illusion of inertia in angular motion.

Thank you for the explanation I appreciate it.

I am still finding it difficult to wrap this concept i updated my question with a new section Based on the comments, please help me if you can

@DPV You confused moment of Inertia with force here by referring "The moment of inertia, as defined, is a measure of the force required to produce angular displacement..."

"Now, a certain torque will result in a certain angular displacement. By varying l
, the displacement will change" ... Here it's not the displacement, it's the angular acceleration. Just like if you apply some force on a body with no other forces acting on it, the body will accelerate as long as you apply the force and next it won't accelerate anymore but will have some velocity. As no other forces are present, it will move in a straight line forever. Same force doesn't imply certain displacement and also same torque doesn't imply certain angular displacement

@DPV You didn't change the question but you have asked a whole new question. I suggest you to remove the torque part and ask a new question. Or my answer will be too long

Updated my statement with angular displacement, which you pointed out, I missed angular in second go.
"Now, a certain torque will result in a certain angular displacement. By varying l , the angular displacement will change"
Also removed the torque question from the update.

@DPV Read my comment correctly. You have misunderstood it. You need to replace 'angular displacement' with 'angular acceleration '

Quantities such as angular velocity and angular acceleration are derived from angular displacement. When torque is applied, it results in angular displacement. The rate of change of angular displacement over time is angular velocity, and the rate of change of angular velocity over time is angular acceleration.

@DPV You should say "as long as the Torque applied". Because even after you stop applying torque, it has some angular velocity and it goes on forever. The angular displacement is only certain to the moment you stop applying torque. After you stop applying torque it's not certain anymore because it will go on forever no matter how much torque is applied

I thought that was implied, as angular displacement only occurs when torque is applied.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The dimensions of moment of inertia can be found by dimensional analysis.
The moment of inertia of an object about a given axis is defined as the ratio of the object's angular momentum about that axis divided by its angular speed (this is the analogue of defining mass as momentum divided by speed). Angular momentum has dimensions $ML^2T^{-1}$ and angular speed has dimensions $T^{-1}$ so moment of inertia must have dimensions
$\displaystyle \frac {ML^2T^{-1}}{T^{-1}} = ML^2$
The $L^2$ term explains the dependence on $r^2$ rather than just $r$.
I think the error in your argument is that you should use torque rather than force, which introduces an extra $r$ term.

Thank you but The ratio definition does not make sense to me,
I am aware of the torque: $ \tau = F \cdot r \cdot \sin(\theta) $, and we have the radius ($r$) and angle ($\theta$), which come into effect while translating force into an angular context.

What i am interested here is the momentum of inertia, the resistance involved to change a angular acceleration or the force required to cause a angular displacement.
In a linear motion the inertia is just the mass.

@DPV If you use the standard definition of moment of inertia you will find it has dimensions $ML^2$. If you wish to use your own definition for whatever you are calling "momentum of inertia", which seems to be a different attribute, then you can do that, but it seems pointless to ask why the standard "moment of inertia" and your own "momentum of inertia" are not calculated in the same way.
